# How to show all date from a certain Month?

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I have database table in postgreSQL name as "time" like:

| Name | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Oct-18 | 2018-10-01 | 2018-10-31 |
| Nov-18 | 2018-11-01 | 2018-11-30 |
| Dec-18 | 2018-12-01 | 2018-12-31 |

I want the result for each month like

| Date | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-10-01 | Oct-18 |
| 2018-10-02 | Oct-18 |
| 2018-10-03 | Oct-18 |
| 2018-10-04 | Oct-18 |
| 2018-10-05 | Oct-18 |
| 2018-10-06 | Oct-18 |
| ----- | ---- |
| 2018-10-31 | Oct-18 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `generate_series()` does what you want:

```
select generate_series(t.start_date, t.end_date, interval '1 day') as date, name
from t;
```

Comment: " Gordon Linoff " thank you dear, it is work correctly. Many many thanks.